# iOS view/controller lifecycle callback on screen unlock or app switch

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nstimer

Is there any function which is get called on view or controller when the user unlocks the phone or comes back to the app? Registering for notifications on app coming to foreground seems to be hacky for me, so I expected something like `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` to be called, but they aren't.

My view has different states, and in one of them it runs a timer (with UI indicating that appropriately). After the timer is fired the view makes some calls to server and updates the UI. Seems like after unlock the NSTimer is continuing from the place the phone was locked, however I would like to refresh it's state, check the timeout left with server and run the timer from correct value (or show "normal" UI if the timeout is already over). I just cannot find a callback which is called for me by the system when it comes back to the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper solution is to have the view controller register with `NSNotificationCenter` for the appropriate app lifecycle notification such as `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` or `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification`.

Remember, these are app events, not view events which is why there are no standard methods in `UIViewController` or `UIView` for these.